# How to relate multiple forms from different controllers?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Certificate and Student models, with one to many relation.

When the user is done making the certificate he is redirected to another page with student form, I dont know how to get the certificate_id or how to relate the student to the last certificate that it was created. help please.

Certificate Controller

```
public function store(StoreCertificateRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    $data['user_id'] = auth()->id();

    Certificate::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('students.create')->with(['success' => 'Certificate has been Saved']);

}
```

Student Controller

```
public function store(StoreStudentRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    Student::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Students were added');
}
```

Comment: Have you added the certificate ID as a query parameter on the redirect URL? That's probably the easiest way. Show your current code please

Comment: I just posted the pics, how can I add it in the create function of students?

Comment: As per the [ask] guide (which you were encouraged to read when creating your question), you must not post pictures of your code. Code is, by nature, text not graphics. Please paste it into your question as text and format it appropriately (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting if you need assistance with that).

Comment: So, does `Certificate::create` return the ID of the created certificate?

Comment: Also you really need to show us the controller action which loads the view containing the student form - the one that your certificate controller redirects to.

Comment: [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts): "*The inserted model instance will be returned to you by the create method*".

Comment: @ADyson Its a function that only returns view of the form, I dont know how to get the certificate ID and put it into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the certificate is already created, you can get that id by assigning a variable to the create, and then return it to the view as $variable->id